# Is this function a norm?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $p$ be a real number such that $p \geq 1$, let $a$ and $b$ be real numbers such that $a < b$, and let $X$ be the set of all the real- (or complex-) valued functions that are defined and continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$. Then $X$ is a vector space over either the set $\mathbb{R}$ of real numbers or the set $\mathbb{C}$ of complex numbers as the field. Am I right?

Now let the function $f \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined as follows: 
$$ f(x) \colon= \sqrt[p]{\int_a^b \ \vert f(t) \vert^p \ \mathrm{d} t } \ \ \ \mbox{ for all } \ x \in X. $$

Then is $f$ a norm on $X$?

What if we define the set $X$ to be the set of all those functions for which the integral in question exists as a finite, real number?

In the first case, I have been able to verify that 
$$f(x) \geq 0 \ \mbox{ for all } \ x \in X.$$
For each $x \in X$, 
$$ f(x) = 0 \ \mbox{ if and only if } \ x = 0. $$
And, for each $x \in X$ and scalar $\alpha$, 
$$f( \alpha x) = \vert \alpha \vert f(x).$$

How to prove the triangle inequality? For $p = 1$, the inequality does indeed hold.

My feeling is there is something like the Holder's inequality for integrals (just like the Holder's inequality for sums) and the Minkowski's inequality for integrals ( just like the Minkowski's inequality for sums), but I'm just not able to prove it.

Moreover, if $X$ is indeed a normed space in either case, is $X$ also a Banach space?

Comment: The Wikipedia pages for Holder's inequality and Minkowski's inequality have the proofs you want. This is a norm, it's called the $L^p $ norm.

Comment: "My feeling is..." You feel right. This is exactly so. You find it on Wikipedia. And no, $X$ is not a Banach space. Its closure is the space $L^p(a,b)$.

Comment: If $X=C([a,b])$, the space of continuous functions on $[a,b]$ then the norm $f$ you defined is well defined for every $x\in X$, the integral always exist. To verify you can use Hölder and Minkowski inequalities for integrals. The space $X$ with that norm is not Banach. For information about spaces with that kind of norm take a look at $L^p$ spaces.

Comment: You should google for $L^p$ space. Notice there are some technical details, like almost everywhere zero functions.